# libwebsockets: Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error

Tags: c, libwebsockets

I'm using [libwebsockets](http://libwebsockets.org/trac/libwebsockets) and I can't compile a demo code implemented by myself.

I created the `context`:

```
struct libwebsocket_context *context;
...
context = libwebsocket_create_context(&info);
```

and when I try to access the members of the struct `libwebsocket_context`, defined in private-libwebsockets.h:

```
struct libwebsocket_context {
    struct pollfd *fds;
    struct libwebsocket **lws_lookup; /* fd to wsi */
    int fds_count;
    int max_fds;
    int listen_port;
    ...
};
```

For example,

```
printf("%d\n", context->listen_port);
```

The compiler returns,

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "struct libwebsocket_context" is not known for gcc - that's why this error occures. Are you sure that definition of this structure is included from .h file? I'd suggest you to insert for example #warning or #error with some message near definition of this struct (in .h file) and try to recompile your program. Your #error or #warning message should appear while compilation. If not - it means that gcc will not also see this struct.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the struct definition is in *private*-libwebsockets.h suggests that you are not supposed to use the struct members directly. You can #include that header to get access to the private  implementation details of the library but you probably should not do it.